# Strange unwanted header when reading text file with MIMEText

Tags: python, text, mime-message

I am writing a program to read from a text file. I have managed to get it to work, but am getting a strange header Which I do not want.

The Text file is called  "SixMonthTextFile.txt and saved with notepad in windows.

The unwanted header I am getting is -

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Body of text read from file here

I have tried stripping the first 3 lines and that is not working, just causes new problems. Any ideas on why it is happening and more importantly how to stop it?

My Code is

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Read an external text file for body of message
fp = open('SixMonthTextFile.txt', 'r')
SixMonthMessage = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

print(SixMonthMessage)
```

The result I get is

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

We would like to remind you that it has been six months
since your last service and its time for a precautionary service
since your equipment needs regular servicing to remain reliable.

Please reply to this email to book your FREE appointment.
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

I want only the original text from the text file as that is going into an email body.

Any ideas on why I am getting the strange unwanted extra header and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Read up on [`get_payload(i=None, decode=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload)

Comment: I have. I have whittled it down to the bare basics.

Comment: Thanks Stovfi I did take a look but I cannot see the answer there. It is something to do with the reading of the file.

Comment: I have got round it by changing the method of reading the file.                                      
        with open('SixMonthTextFile.txt', 'r') as file:
        SixMonthTextFile = file.read()

Comment: Ah, Ok re-read the Get_payload() and I understand now that it can be used to remove the unwanted lines. Thanks stovfl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried stovfl's suggestion and played with adding get_payload(),'3\n' to the MIMEText(fp.read() statement and it removed the unwanted header but also messed up the format of the text file and I still had an unuseable result.

I got around the problem by coming at a different angle and replaced fp = open() etc with

open('SixMonthTextFile.txt', 'r') as file: 
    SixMonthTextFile = file.read()

'''

This gave me text that could then be used as formatted in the text file for insertion into the email.

```
def sendsixmonthemail(address, EmailTo):
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Read an external text file for body of message
with open('SixMonthTextFile.txt', 'r') as file:
    SixMonthTextFile = file.read()



host="smtp.gmail.com"
email="myemailaddress@gmail.com"
password = "123456786"

from_addr='myemailaddress@gmail.com'
to_addr=EmailTo
reply_address = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"

msg=MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']=from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['reply-to'] = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
msg['subject']='FREE 6 month Service Reminder for' + " " + address

#Data read from Text File
body= str(SixMonthTextFile)


msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

mail=smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host,465)
mail.login(email,password)
text=msg.as_string()

mail.sendmail(email,to_addr,text)
mail.quit()
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to use this code, the "address" variable is the clients street address read from the client database for inclusion into the 'subject' of the email. Both "address" and "email" are being passed from the main program that reads the data from the database for conditions where it has been six months since the last service.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wanted to be able to easily edit the message being included into the email was so we did not have to redo the program each time we want to include anything into the emails. It also made it easier to copy and modify the process for clients who only get an annual reminder who get a different message.